# Excel - Average a group of cells where the size of the group isn't fixed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have several groups of cells, each with representing a batch of goods produced to a certain 'Cutting Pattern', which is just a number of circles cut out of a piece of wood of a certain size. I want to average each Cutting Patterns total production. I don't know how to get Excel to stop at the end of a batch and to recognise two different batches of the same template.

This image shows the layout of the patterns that are produced and how their figures are laid out:

[image: This image shows the layout of the patterns that are produced and how their figures are laid out.]

It shows one continuous run so this would all be one batch, if the template were to change to a different size then that would be a new batch, if the template were to then change back that would also be a new batch.

This image shows the data I am working with to help generate the report.

[image: This image shows the data I am working with to help generate the report.]

As you can see each sheet has it's own ID in the AU column with the smaller patterns in the AT column.

How can I get an average batch size for each pattern without having to do it all manually?

Comment: There is no AU column in your screenshot